# java.util.logger.Logger.getAnonymousLogger() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, logging, japplet, signed-applet

I just upgraded my Java plugin to 1.7.0_25, which caused a fatal error with an applet I wrote several years ago (and have been maintaining since).

Early in the applet's init() method I call

```
logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
```

This call has been running since Java 1.4.2 without a problem. Now, with Java 1.7.0_25 (on Windows 7 at least; I've no Mac or Linux machine to test with here), the first time the applet is loaded, it works just fine. However if the applet's browser page is closed and the page loaded again, the applet fails with the following console message:

```
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 756747 us, pluginInit dt 76093467 us, TotalTime: 76850214 us java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doSetParent(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.optix.applet.viewer.ObjectViewer.init(ObjectViewer.java:214)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

To load the applet again, I must close and restart the browser.

This has never happened with any previous Java release since java.util.logger was introduced in Java 1.4.

There should be no permissions problem: I've added to META-INF/MANFEST.MF the new attributes

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
```

as called for in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/no_redeploy.html.
The applet is signed with a current GoDaddy certificate and timestamped.

I found that if I create the logger with

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(String);
```

the applet will load every time.

I can find nothing on this error. Has anyone seen it? Would anyone know what caused it to appear with Java 1.7.0_25 or why the call would work once in a browser session but not a second time?

Comment: Raise a new bug report and see what Oracle says.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem on Linux.

This is the relevant [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017174) from Oracle.

Comment: Yes, that's it. And duplicate "JI-9004402 - NullPointerException from Logger.doSetParent in applet" is my submission made June 24th, with example, stack trace, etc. At that time, 4 days after this bug report, there was still no listing for it in the bug database. Thanks.