# NPE with logging while launching webstart on jre7 update 40

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

My application was running fine until I upgraded my jre to 7u40. When my application is initializing, it's doing Logger.getLogger("ClassName"), and I'm getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.Application.Applet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setParent(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.doSetParent(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$LogNode.walkAndSetParent(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$LoggerContext.addLocalLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$LoggerContext.addLocalLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.addLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

The exception is coming from this line:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName());
```

Could it be because of any sideeffects with fix https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017174 ?

A workaround is to open the java control center and enable logging. This is a concern since by default "Enable Logging" is unchecked. If I select "Enable Logging", the application starts fine.

Comment: Opened http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=9007085

Comment: Related: [java-util-logger-logger-getanonymouslogger-throws-nullpointerexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241970/java-util-logger-logger-getanonymouslogger-throws-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be fixed in java7 update 45.

Answer (score 0):

Try to package `java.util.logging.*` with your app in a JAR, and make sure it's on the classpath. That way it is always available. Also, what does your logging.properties look like?